# Should I install Opera 12 or OmniWeb browser for my (dated) iMac OSX 10.5.8?

Tags: macos, safari, imac, leopard

Greetings: I've been reading the helpful comments regarding what browser is compatible with a dated OS. My Safari browser is 5.0.6. I'm going to paste my query here. I posted it on another Mac forum whose members get a little testy toward those who are not tech savvy:

I'm a senior (and I'm not talking high school) who's had Macs since the early '90s. However, I tend to cling to whatever works. Change, particularly technical change, is intimidating. As a result, I've been plugging along on my comfortable iMac for a long time. As you can imagine, things are getting weird: pages won't load, the system quits, I get shut out of many sites, etc. I tried going with the Firefox browser but a message said I don't have the requirements. I realize someone else had a similar problem and I read the answers but am as confused as ever. I don't need the latest technology. I just need to get back on track with the least amount of stress. My question: Should I take it to the Mac store or is there something I can do at home? Needless to say, I need to keep it simple. Thanks in advance for anything you can share with me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) as it is a clone of the latest firefox.

The PPC version will work on an Intel machine via emulation. Pick the g3 version.

https://code.google.com/p/tenfourfox/wiki/WhichVersion